# Trying to move emails in a loop, but not all get moved in the first run

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

The VBA code does not move all emails with a certain words in the Subject "has been updated" and "Item" from the inbox to the subfolder "Neu". Emails should be already read. After 5-6 iterations , all emails will be moved. But why doesn't it work immediately after the first time of code running? Maybe you have faced the same problem? Out of 46 emails, 26 of them are moved firstly, then 39, then 44 and then 46.

Thank you very much in advance!

```
Sub Emails_Outlook_Transport()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

    Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set olFldr = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Set Items = olFldr.Items

    Dim newFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set newFldr = olFldr.Folders("Neu")

    Dim msg As Object
    Dim olMailItem As MailItem
    Dim Found As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each msg In Items        
        If TypeOf msg Is MailItem And msg.UnRead = False Then
            Set olMailItem = msg

            If InStr(olMailItem.Subject, "has been updated") > 0 And InStr(olMailItem.Subject, "Item") > 0 Then
                olMailItem.Move newFldr
            End If 
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

No error messages, just not a proper work of the code

Comment: You cannot see any errors because you must remove `On Error Resume Next` to see your error messages! This line hides **all** error messages until `End  Sub`, but the errors still occur (you just cannot see their message boxes). To fix your errors you need to make them visible first. Therefore remove that line and see where you get errors and which. • To debug your code then go through the code using F8 and check the values of your variables to see what is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! However, the code still works even after removing "On Error Resume Next" and no errors come out.

Comment: Did you go through the code step by step using F8 to see *where* it goes wrong? What was the result of your investigation?

Comment: I did, but to be honest, there are 347 messages and I have not checked all of them at once. However, I reached the point when 1 message (that stayed between two others)  was skipped, and code continued to analyse the rest of them. On the second trial, that message was already accounted. That is why after the first iteration, there are just 26 or 23 emails identified, then 39 or 33 and etc till 46. Each time the number of identified emails during the first iteration changes, but between 26, 23 and 22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

- Apparently when the items are moved around, it messes with the item being referred in the loop in case of `For Each` loop

**Solution:**

- Work a Loop after counting the Items and Backwards.So that each item is referred by an Index.

**Try this:**

```
Sub Emails_Outlook_Transport()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Dim olFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set olFldr = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Set Items = olFldr.Items

    Dim newFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set newFldr = olFldr.Folders("Neu")

    Dim msg As Object
    Dim olMailItem As MailItem
    Dim Found As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        If TypeOf Items(i) Is MailItem And Items(i).UnRead = False Then

            Set olMailItem = Items(i)

            If InStr(olMailItem.Subject, "has been updated") > 0 And InStr(olMailItem.Subject, "Item") > 0 Then
                olMailItem.Move newFldr
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Was about to post that :) • But highly recommended to remove `On Error Resume Next`  or replace it with a proper error handling:  [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: Thanks @Pᴇʜ .. I actually removed it while testing. But then while making it compatible for OP, I missed removing it.

Comment: @Peh, thank you very much for your help!!! I will remove "On Error Resume Next"! Thank you!