# Outlook/Excel VBA - Not Loop Through All Msg

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I currently have the below VBA code which has the following issue: once I move the msg to the subfolder the For Next loop will not then go to the next msg in the original Outlook folder.

If I take out the
`msg.move olInboxFolder.Folders("Forms to do").Folders("Forms completed")` 
line of code it does work. So this line seems to be the issue.

```
Dim msg as MailItem
Dim olSubFolder As MAPIFolder

Set olSubFolder = olInboxFolder.Folders("Forms to do")

For Each msg In olSubFolder.Items ' for each message in the subfolder

   'Do stuff

   msg.move olInboxFolder.Folders("Forms to do").Folders("Forms completed")

Next msg
```

Has anyone any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks it did - just posted at the same time as you.

Answer (score 0):

OK credit has to go to this post that helped me solve the problem:

[Trying to move emails in a loop, but not all get moved in the first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57391257/trying-to-move-emails-in-a-loop-but-not-all-get-moved-in-the-first-run)

I changed my code to the following:

```
Dim msg as MailItem
Dim olSubFolder As MAPIFolder

Set olSubFolder = olInboxFolder.Folders("Forms to do")

Dim i As Integer

For i = olSubFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1 

    set msg = olSubFolder.Items(i)

   'Do stuff

   msg.move olInboxFolder.Folders("Forms to do").Folders("Forms completed")

Next
```

I hope this helps someone else.